# Deixar efeito mais suave

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como deixo esse efeito mais suave?

```
$j(window).scroll(function () {
    console.log($j(document).scrollTop());
    if ($j(document).scrollTop() >= 300) {
        $j('.logo img').attr('src', 'http://i.imgur.com/499DSOf.png').addClass('logozinho');
        $j('.header-container').css({"borderTop":"none";})
    } else {
        $j('.logo img').attr('src', 'http://roupasatacado.dev.bizcommerce.com.br/media/wysiwyg/LOGO/loja-logo_1_.png').removeClass('logozinho');
        $j('.header-container').css({"borderTop":"1.5rem solid rgba(67, 67, 67, 0.12)"});
    }
});
```

Se fosse por exemplo, um efeito toggle, era so por a "velocidade" em MS que ficaria bom, mas e no caso desse meu código, tem como deixar mais suave? Trocando de um efeito pro outro...

Comment: Qual é o parametro que queres suavizar? `borderTop`?

Comment: No caso, todos ali. A troca de SRC, que no caso vai trocar a imagem, e não queria deixar aquele negocio "seco" e a borda também. Quando adicionar e remover a borda, também queria deixar mais suave.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Talvez o [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) do jquery seja o que procuras, ele executa uma animação personalizada das propriedades do CSS, segue um exemplo no teu contexto:

```
$( ".header-container" ).animate({
    borderTop: none
  }, 5000, function() {
    // animação completa.
});
```

E um snippet contendo também uma maneira de suavizar a troca do atributo `src` com o método [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) do jquery:

```js
$("#go").click(function() {
  $("#block").animate({
    width: "70%",
    opacity: 0.4,
    marginLeft: "0.6in",
    fontSize: "3em",
  }, 1500);
});


$("#go2").click(function() {
  $("img").fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $("img").attr('src', 'https://www.stoughtonutilities.com/images/TOD-clock.jpg');
    $("img").fadeIn('slow');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="go">Animar</button>
<div id="block">Olá!</div>

<button id="go2" style="position:absolute;">Suavizar Troca Src</button>
<image id="img" style="margin-top:30px;" src="https://c.tadst.com/gfx/sunrise.png">
```

Comment: Obrigado Mathias, pela resposta outra vez. Mas a troca de SRC ali, eu também queria "suavizar", seria também com o animate(), caso desse?

Comment: @LucasCarvalho adicionei a resposta uma maneira de suavizar a troca do SRC também.

Comment: Obrigado Mathias, mas ta dando erro, está dando "none is not defined" Eu fiz assim: 


$j(window).scroll(function () {
    console.log($j(document).scrollTop());
    if ($j(document).scrollTop() >= 300) {
        $j('.logo img').attr('src', 'http://i.imgur.com/499DSOf.png').addClass('logozinho');
  $j('.header-container').animate({
   borderTop: none
  }, 300);
    } else {
        $j('.logo img').attr('src', 'http://roupasatacado.dev.bizcommerce.com.br/media/wysiwyg/LOGO/loja-logo_1_.png').removeClass('logozinho');
    }
}); 

Eu uso $j porque la usamos também o prototype.

Comment: @LucasCarvalho seguinte, vou tentar editar a reposta de modo que o exemplo fique o mais parecido com o que tu precisa.

Comment: Muito obrigado, desculpa eu ser leigo ainda, ainda estou estudando, e obrigado pela paciência!

Comment: @LucasCarvalho sem problema nenhum, estamos aqui p/ isso, segue um [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mathiasfcx/5u9u4mwx/4/) com a suavização do logo, nota que não uso $j e sim $, em relação a borda vou ficar te devendo, não consegui alterar somente o border-top (de maneira suave) com o animate, espero que ajude.